# Can we aggregate and group-by in WPF with LINQ or something?

Tags: c#, wpf, linq

I have the following data structure:
   List myOrders

So it is a list of Data (seen below) based on orders recieved today (so you can duplicate if different people purchase the same items multiple times).

```
Data
{
  string itemName
  double itemQuantiy
  string partName
  double partQuantity
}
```

As an example the list looks like this when populated:

```
  itemName   itemQuantity   partName   partQuantity
  A          1              alpha      5
  A          1              beta       2
  A          1              delta      100
  B          1              alpha      17
  B          1              gamma      2000
  A          2              alpha      10
  A          2              beta       4
  A          2              delta      200
```

As you can see from the table above item A has 3 parts (alpha, beta, delta) and item B has two parts (alpha, gamma) all with their respective quantities, and in this example item A was ordered twice (first 3 rows are the first order for 1 unit of A, last 3 rows for 2 units of A).

I need to present this to the user, but it should be grouped-by item and the quantities should be aggregated.

The end result (shown on-screen to the user) should look like this:

```
  itemName   itemQuantity   partName   partQuantity
  A          3              alpha      15
                            beta       6
                            delta      300
  B          1              alpha      17
                            gamma      2000
```

Can this be done using something like LINQ or maybe something in WPF?
(or any other way you might suggest - I am at a loss right now).

Comment: ... I think that although you could do what you're looking for, a better solution would be to create two objects rather than one. The first being `Data` and the second being `Item` where `Item` would contain, say, a list of parts associated with that item and their respective quantities per item and then `Data` would contain `Item` - Just seems like cleaner structure to achieve what you want and it also allows for future growth.

Comment: Agreed - this is but a small piece of the puzzel and sadly I have to (at one point) generate the data like this. I could do an extra step after to reform it more appropriatly but I don't see the point if this is only a throw-away for the UI. The base level data has a structure (somewhat like yours) of a legacy system I cannot touch

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's the Linq way.

```
List<Data> myOrders = GetList();

IEnumerable<Data> groupingQuery = myOrders
  .GroupBy(data => new { data.itemName, data.partName } )
  .Select(g => new Data()
  {
    itemName = g.Key.itemName,
    partName = g.Key.partName,
    itemQuantity = g.Sum(x => x.itemQuantity),
    partQuantity = g.Sum(x => x.partQuantity)
  })
  .OrderBy(data => data.itemName)
  .ThenBy(data => data.partName);
```

---

Or you could turn the Data into Items and Parts...

```
List<Item> items = (
  from data in myOrders
  group data by data.itemName into itemGroup
  let partGroups = itemGroup.GroupBy(x => x.partName)
  select new Item()
  {
    itemName = itemGroup.Key,
    itemQuantity = partGroups.Min(partGroup => partGroup.Sum(x => x.itemQuantity)),
    Parts = (
      from partGroup in partgroups
      select new Part() { partName = partGroup.Key, partQuantity = partGroup.Sum(x => x.partQuantity) }
    ).ToList();
  }).ToList();
```

---

There's some potentially inconsistent data here that makes this grouping more difficult.

```
itemName   itemQuantity   partName   partQuantity
A          1              alpha      5
A          2              beta       2
A          1              delta      100
```

Do I have 1 A or 2 A's?

Comment: I do not want to show A multiple times, it needs to be like in the example I posted (when shown to the user). One A with multiple parts and multiple quantities for each part. In your example you have itemName A twice (for different parts I gather) but this is not what I need to do.

Comment: The "example" is one of bad input.  If those two lines are the input, the correct output is not clear.  A should have 1, 2, or 3 itemquantity in the output for those two lines.

Comment: Oh ... for each order of A you will ALWAYS have the 3 rows (alpha, beta, and delta), the difference is the quantity. But you could never have JUST those 2 rows you show in your example

Comment: Ok, updated the example.  Now do you see the problem?  The number of A's is redundantly expressed on different lines, which is a problem if the lines don't agree.

Comment: Again that example isn't possible (as per my system design today), you will always have 3 A's with the same itemQuantity as this represent an order of item A (and X of them). So it will always be in triples ... So in your example the 2nd row isn't possible (it will be A 1 beta 2).

The example I provided is the only real way I will support this (if what you say happens there is a bug elsewhere in the system as the data should never show that).

Does that help? Will your code now be able to output it in the same format as my "end result" example?

Answer (score 0):

You can use LINQ GroupBy method (http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.linq.enumerable.groupby.aspx)

Something like this:

```
List<Data> data = ...;
var groupedItems = data.GroupBy(d => d.itemName);
```

For WPF you can use grouping feature (ItemsControl.GroupStyle and so on, for example for datagrid: http://wpftutorial.net/DataGrid.html#grouping you can google to find more tutorials)